# What is the correct way of encoding a large batch of documents with sentence transformers/pytorch?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, nlp, pytorch

I am having issues encoding a large number of documents (more than a million) with the [sentence_transformers](https://www.sbert.net/index.html) library.

Given a very similar [corpus](https://rentry.co/zt4a2) list of strings. When I do:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
embedder = SentenceTransformer('msmarco-distilbert-base-v2')
corpus_embeddings = embedder.encode(corpus, convert_to_tensor=False)
```

After some hours, the process seems to be stuck, as it never finishes and when checking the process viewer nothing is running.

As I am suspicious that this is a ram issue (the GPU board doesn't have enough memory to fit everything in a single step) I tried to split the corpus into batches, transform them into NumPy arrays, and concat them into a single matrix as follows:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
import torch
from loguru import logger
import glob
from natsort import natsorted



def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=np.nan):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

embedder = SentenceTransformer('msmarco-distilbert-base-v2')

for j, e in enumerate(list(grouper(corpus, 3))):
    try:
#         print('------------------')
        for i  in filter(lambda v: v==v, e):
            corpus_embeddings=embedder.encode(i, convert_to_tensor=False)
            torch.save(corpus_embeddings, f'/Users/user/Downloads/embeddings_part_{j}.npy')
    except TypeError:
        print(j, e)
        logger.debug("TypeError in batch {batch_num}", batch_num=j)

l = []
for e in natsorted(glob.glob("/Users/user/Downloads/*.npy")):
    l.append(torch.load(e))
    corpus_embeddings = np.vstack(l)
corpus_embeddings
```

Nevertheless, the above procedure doesn't seem to work. The reason is that when I try with a small sample of the corpus with and without the batch approach the matrices I get are different for example:

Without batch approach:

```
array([[-0.6828216 , -0.26541945,  0.31026787, ...,  0.19941986,
         0.02366139,  0.4489861 ],
       [-0.45781   , -0.02955275,  1.0897563 , ..., -0.20077021,
        -0.37821707,  0.2248317 ],
       [ 0.8532193 , -0.13642257, -0.8872398 , ..., -0.57482916,
         0.12760726, -0.66986346],
       ...,
       [-0.04036704,  0.06745373, -0.6010259 , ..., -0.08174597,
        -0.18513843, -0.64744204],
       [-0.30782765, -0.04935509, -0.11624689, ...,  0.10423593,
        -0.14073376, -0.09206307],
       [-0.77139395, -0.08119706,  0.43753916, ...,  0.1653319 ,
         0.06861683, -0.16276269]], dtype=float32)
```

With batch approach:

```
array([[ 0.8532191 , -0.13642241, -0.8872397 , ..., -0.5748289 ,
         0.12760736, -0.6698637 ],
       [ 0.3679317 , -0.21968201,  0.9932826 , ..., -0.86282325,
        -0.04683857,  0.18995859],
       [ 0.23026675,  0.69587034, -0.8116473 , ...,  0.23903558,
         0.413471  , -0.23438476],
       ...,
       [ 0.923319  ,  0.4152724 , -0.3153545 , ..., -0.6863369 ,
         0.01149149, -0.51300013],
       [-0.30782777, -0.04935484, -0.11624689, ...,  0.10423636,
        -0.1407339 , -0.09206269],
       [-0.77139413, -0.08119693,  0.43753892, ...,  0.16533189,
         0.06861652, -0.16276267]], dtype=float32)
```

What is the correct way of doing the above batch procedure?

**UPDATE**

After inspecting the above batch procedure, I found that I was able to get the same matrix output with and without the batching when I set to `1` the batch size of the above code `(enumerate(list(grouper(corpus, 1))))`. Therefore, my question is, what is the correct way of applying the encoder to a large set of documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line [here](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py#L152) sorts the input by text length before doing the encode. I have no idea why.

So, either comment those lines out or copy them to your code like

```
length_sorted_idx = np.argsort([-embedder._text_length(sen) for sen in corpus])
corpus_sorted = [corpus[idx] for idx in length_sorted_idx]
```

Then use the `corpus_sorted` to encode and map the output back using `length_sorted_idx`.

Or just encode it one by one and you won't need to care about which output is from which text.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Nevertheless, after using the above lines of code to re-sort for second time the lists I am still getting different matrices without and with the batch process. Any idea what else could make this issue?

Comment: No idea. I only tried with the first few examples in the link and it work fine in my machine though.

Comment: Is one-by-one encoding suffers the same issue?

Comment: Thanks again, another thing that I noted is that when the batch size changes (in this case the batch size is 3) the matrices are different. Is this the correct way of doing this batch process?

Comment: That is even weirder since output changing with batch size is, as far as I know, a behavior of `Batch Normalization` but `encode` has `self.eval` [here](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py#L129)

Comment: Yes, I was able to get the same final matrices with and without the batch processing when I set the batch size to `1`

Comment: There is a parameter called `batch_size` [here](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py#L107) maybe you can try change it to 1 or other numbers and see what happen?

Comment: So with the batch size I dont need to do my self all the batch process? For the large version of `corpus` I only need to reduce the size of the batch?

Comment: No idea. I just see the code but haven't try it yet. Already turned off the PC

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the transformers are supposed to encode based on the nearby words basically the so-called `Attention` but when you make batches the words change. For example -
Without batching you had 100 words in corpus and the Attention is used for all 100 words but with batching you now have only 25, 25, 25, 25 words in each batch then the `Attention` is used on them only, and hence the values from the rest of 75 words are not there. So basically there shouldn't be a way to implement it using batching and get the same results because while computing `Multi-head Attention` all the words should be present.

This is different from static encoding where the encoding of a word is irrelavent to its nebouring words and context.